# Как правильно собрать библиотеку vue с vuex?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

У меня есть приложение в, котором присутвует уомпонент manager. Я хочу выложить его в npm.
Сейчас я делаю это так:

1. в /src/lib.js экспортирую этот компонент

   import Manager from "./components/manager/Manager";

   export default Manager;
2. Запускаю скрипт

   vue-cli-service build --target lib --name appedu_tasks src/lib.js
3. В самом компоненте импортирую vuex

После билда, публикации и подключения ошибка. В хуке beforeMount я обращаюсь к this.$store

Error in beforeMount hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'commit' of undefined"

Проверял значение this.$store и оно равно undefined